# FileDialog select target file?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

So! 
A user right clicks any file on their computer and a custom made option opens up my program, on Form_load I ask the user to choose a file however, I want that file to be the file they opened the program with.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                source = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: i think u want to launch your program with arguments, Where the argument is file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your program is associated with any *file extension*, Windows will pass the file name via *command line parameter*, so you can examine them:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
  String[] data = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

  // 0th parameter is executable itself, we want the 1st parameter     
  if (data.Length > 1)
    openFileDialog1.FileName = data[1];

  if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    source = openFileDialog1.FileName;
  }
  else
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you asking about 'Send to' menu in Windows context menu -> You should put your application in special folder as described here: [How-to geek: Customize the Send To Menu in Windows 10, 8, 7, or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/)  and you will receive the full path including file name as first parameter in `args` in function `Main()`